# The libgit2 examples are not building properly

Tags: libgit2

I have built `libgit2` on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, and everything seemed fine. I ran `make` in the `/examples` directory and when I try to run `./log` I get the following:

`./log: error while loading shared libraries: libgit2.so.26: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

But, in the `/build` folder I indeed have both `libgit2.so` and `libgit2.so.26` so I am not really sure what I am missing. I can post more info if it is needed. I am using `cmake version 3.5.1`.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question - we've cleaned up the way we build examples to be more current!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Makefile` in the examples will provide guidelines for usage, which should be suitable when you have actually installed libgit2 into system library locations.

To build the examples within the source directory, you should use cmake to build the examples.  Given a fresh configuration:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
$ cmake --build .

  ...truncated...

$ examples/log
commit 8ac8c78c35905f7f9cc37f240c3d633a7cc5a5e3
Merge: 34ec6f3 4955125
Author: Edward Thomson <ethomson@edwardthomson.com>
Date:   Mon Oct  9 15:15:08 2017 +0100

    Merge pull request #4356 from pks-t/pks/static-clar

    cmake: use static dependencies when building static libgit2

    ...truncated...
```